# Generate a Dex file with python or other language

Tags: python, dalvik, dex

Is it possible to generate dalvik bytecode at runtime using a language such as python, perl or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to create a smali compatible file and compile it with smali http://code.google.com/p/smali/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [android-scripting](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/), a toolkit for running Python, Perl, JRuby, Lua, BeanShell, JavaScript, Tcl, and shell.